# Completing a dictionary for an sqlite execute parameter

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I'm trying to feed data obtained from a JSON file into an SQLite database. So my JSON data contains an array of fields, each of which map nicely to a table column (there's no further nesting of values). Therefore, each JSON object is a dictionary that I can then bind to the values in an insert statement.

```
row_values = {'id': 1, 'field1': 'some value', 'field2': 'some value', 'field3': 'some value'}
sql = "insert into my_table (id, field1, field2, field3) values (:id, :field1, :field2, :field3)"
cursor.execute(sql, row_values)
```

Problem is, not all fields are always present in the JSON input, so my dictionary "row_values" may, for one object, be missing field2 for instance (yielding an error " You did not supply a value for binding x"). What's the best way to get a complete dictionary where missing keys are present but simply have empty strings as value? I thought of first creating a dictionary with all the required keys and values as empty strings ({'id': '', 'field1': '', 'field2': '', 'field3': ''}), then assign the values from the JSON object ({'id': '', 'field1': 'some value', 'field3': 'some value'}), but that doesn't seem to maintain the dictionary entries with missing keys.

So I'm probably doing it wrong, and not even sure if it's the best way to go...

Thanks in advance for your help!

R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use defaultdict from collections, to create a dictionnary that will give an empty string if you ask for a not existing key

```
from collections import defaultdict
row_values = {'id': 1, 'field1': 'some value', 'field3': 'some value'}
final_row = defaultdict(str, row_values)

>>> final_row['field1']
'some value'
>>> final_row['field2']
''
```

Comment: That works like a charm! I was hoping for something that easy! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize a dictionary with empty strings as values and then copy the keys from source dictionary, like this

```
# missing field2
row_values = {'id': 1, 'field1': 'some value', 'field3': 'some value'}

final_row = {'id':'','field1':'','field2':'','field3':''}

for k in final_row.keys():
    final_row[k] = row_values.get(k,'')
# use this dict for sqlite
print final_row
```